# Export the IPA : An App ID with identifier XXX is not available

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am working for a Client and created an `iPhone app`. My client gave me the `AdHoc provisioning profile`,`certificate` and `private key` for the `certificate` which i already imported in to my `keychain`. Then i tried to `archieve` the project with the given `provisioning profile` and `certificate`. I am not a member of his team in the `apple developer portal` and i am a member of another team which do not have any `app` with this `app` `bundleID`. , i am getting the following `error` which i try to export the `archieve`.

[image]

Can i archieve the project and export the IPA if am not a member of a team but i have the provisioning profile and certificate for that app?

Can any body guide me how i can export the created archieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be a team member since the provisioning profile includes your personal information and uses that in Xcode to build the app.

Another workaround could be to set up your own provisioning profile for the app and include
the devices you want to run it with.

However the most simple solution would be to add you as a team member and to create a fresh certificate.

Comment: But if create my own provisiong profile then there will an issue of the push messages. The push messages should come from the server of my client instead of my own push server. Do you think this will be an issue?

Comment: You could generate a new certificate for push notifications in member center, download it and place it on your clients server. Then with your freshly created provisioning profile you could receive notifications from that server.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot create an IPA if you are not a member of the team.

Things would become easy if your client can add you as a member of his team and tada you can export IPA!